# Android custom MapView question

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

Can I set api Key programmatically or can I set it from xml to my custom mapView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained here : http://code.google.com/intl/fr/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView.html , you can either put your api key in your xml file, or pass it programmatically through the MapView constructor.

Comment: I try to put it programmatically through the MapView constructor. But it dous't work. 
07-18 12:35:25.846: ERROR/MapActivity(29061): Couldn't get connection factory client

Comment: Did you try your app on a real device ? Because it seems there is a bug with the emulator giving that error sometimes.

Comment: I try it on Samsung Galaxy Tab

Comment: yes, but I don't understand what is the problem, when I debug it in my device it show the map, but when I release it to android market it doesn't show the map.((

Comment: It's because you don't use the good API key. You should have to keys, the one you use when you debug your app (linked to your debug certificate) and the one you use when you release your app to the market. This is explained here : http://code.google.com/intl/fr/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-overview.html#sign

Comment: @Lyrkan let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1569/discussion-between-george-and-lyrkan)